# Filtering stocks by dividend yield

Tags: python, comparative-review, hash-map, finance

I have a dict of stock tickers (KEY) and a data point (VALUE; e.g. dividend yield).

I want to know which tickers have a value between a specified min and max value.

#### Given

```
data = {'KO': 1, 'WMT': 0, 'IBM': 3, 'PG': 2}
gte = 1
lte = 2
```

#### Func1

```
def func1(data, gte=None, lte=None):
    data_set = set(data)
    gte_set = set(filter(lambda k: data[k] >= gte, data)) if gte else data_set
    lte_set = set(filter(lambda k: data[k] <= lte, data)) if lte else data_set
    return data_set.intersection(gte_set, lte_set)
```

#### Func2

```
import operator
def func2(data, gte=None, lte=None):
    if gte is None and lte is None:
        return data
    #without dict data gets modified
    _data = dict(data)
    for k, v in data.items():
        if gte and operator.lt(v, gte):
                del _data[k]
        if lte and operator.gt(v, lte):
                del _data[k]
    return set(_data)
```

#### Func3

```
def func3(
    data,
    gte=float('-inf'),
    lte=float('inf')
):
    return set(filter(
        lambda k: gte <= data[k] <= lte,
        data
    ))
```

#### Example

```
func1(data, gte=gte, lte=lte) == {'PG', 'KO'}
func2(data, gte=gte, lte=lte) == {'PG', 'KO'}
func3(data, gte=gte, lte=lte) == {'PG', 'KO'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would rename the bounds to be more meaningful, from `gte` to `min_value`, and from `lte` to `max_value`.

---

Function 1 comes close to being a good idea, but could be implemented more smartly.  The special treatment of any falsy value (notably 0) to skip filtering is probably a bad idea.  The set intersection operation should be avoidable.

```
def func1_improved(data, min_value=None, max_value=None):
    if min_value is not None:
        data = {(k, v) for k, v in data if v >= min_value}
    if max_value is not None:
        data = {(k, v) for k, v in data if v <= max_value}
    return data.keys()
```

---

Function 2 is not equivalent to the other two: it returns a dictionary rather than a key set.  It suffers from the problem that it sometimes returns the original dictionary, and sometimes returns a copy.  It also treats 0 as a special parameter value.

```
def func2_improved(data, min_value=None, max_value=None):
    data = dict(data)    # Make a copy
    for k, v in data.items():
        if min_value is not None and v <= min_value:
                del data[k]
        if max_value is not None and v >= max_value:
                del data[k]
    return data.keys()
```

---

Function 3 is quite good, especially when formatted as a one-liner using a set comprehension:

```
def func3_improved(data, min_value=float('-inf'), max_value=float('inf')):
    return set(k for (k, v) in data.items() if min_value <= v <= max_value)
```

That is my recommendation.  You could eliminate some comparisons by making special cases for when `min_value` or `max_value` is missing, but I'd prefer not to ruin the elegance of the one-line solution.

Comment: Why is it "improved" to use `set` comprehension vs. `filter()`?

Comment: That's what the language feature is designed for. Reasoning from the claim that [list comprehensions are faster than `map()`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops), it makes sense that calling `set()` with a generator expression should be faster too. The comprehension considers key-value pairs. On the other hand, the `filter()` needs to construct a list of keys as candidates, and call a lambda for each (doing a dict lookup as well). That said, I don't think that the `filter()` version would be _bad_.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the wiki resource :) +1